# Using Postman tool to create nodes in Neo4j

Tags: rest, neo4j

I have just started using Neo4j and Cypher. I am trying to create a node from Postman using Rest API calls.

When I send the postman call, I get a Status: 201 Created, which is great.
But when I send the MATCH call to check if the node has been created, I get an empty response.

**CREATE REST CALL**

[image]

Response:

```
{
  "commit": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/43/commit",
  "results": [
    {
      "columns": [],
      "data": [],
      "stats": {
        "contains_updates": true,
        "nodes_created": 1,
        "nodes_deleted": 0,
        "properties_set": 2,
        "relationships_created": 0,
        "relationship_deleted": 0,
        "labels_added": 1,
        "labels_removed": 0,
        "indexes_added": 0,
        "indexes_removed": 0,
        "constraints_added": 0,
        "constraints_removed": 0
      }
    }
  ],
  "transaction": {
    "expires": "Mon, 06 Feb 2017 21:03:06 +0000"
  },
  "errors": []
}
```

But if I create it from the Web Client, I can see those in my get call from REST API. 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aah.. got the answer. The URL for CREATE is 
http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit
instead of
http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/

Also, if you need to get the object back in the same call, you could do this

```
{
  "statements": [
    {
      "statement": "CREATE (a:Person { name: 'Adam', title: 'some guy' }) RETURN a",
      "parameters": {},
      "resultDataContents": [
        "row",
        "graph"
      ],
      "includeStats": true
    }
  ]
}
```